# Can't get ipython console in spyder

Tags: ipython, spyder

I'm having trouble getting an **ipython** console in Spyder. It only offers a **python** interpreter under the "interpreters" menu.

I've seen this issue for a couple of others in Stackoverflow, but didn't have much joy with the proffered solutions.

I'm running linux Mint 16 and have installed both ipython (v 1.1.0) and Spyder (v 2.2.1) the easy way via the Mint *Software Manager*. I made sure that I also installed **ipython-qtconsole** and verified that I could run it from a terminal (i.e. ipython qtconsole).

I can activate an ipython console using the following commands in a Spyder python console:

```
import IPython
IPython.start_ipython()
```

though the font coloring is strange and doesn't work well on a white background (e.g. error messages in yellow and light green). It would be nice anyway to be able to start ipython the normal way from the Spyder menu.

Comment: If you go to 'Help', 'Optional dependencies', you can see if it has found a compatible IPython.

Comment: I have no such menu item (Spyder 2.2.1).

Comment: (*Spyder dv here*) Please update to Spyder 2.3.1 and try again

Comment: Have updated to Spyder 2.2.5 and all good now. Sorry for the late response. I had missed the notices and had switched in the meantime to running spyder in my win10 partition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to install `python-zmq` for Python 2 and `python3-zmq` for Python 3.

I use Ubuntu 14.04, so:

`sudo apt-get install python-zmq python3-zmq`

Answer (score 3):

I'm also using Linux Mint (18.1, at this time) and I have faced the same issue.

What solved this for me was installing Ipython3 Qt console (that, of course, should be Ipython Qt console if you're using Python 2.x).

In case you have it installed, check if you have the latest version 
(In Linux Mint you can do this through Synaptic, aptitude or apt-get.)

Comment: Yep, have that installed too, and is working fine now. Thx