# How to use IPython magic commands within the Spyder editor?

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I'm using Spyder as my IDE, and I'd like to know if I can use IPython magic (e.g. `%reset`) within the text editor and have it interpreted correctly within my IPython client.

Currently I get syntax errors (it's not wrong) but I was wondering if there was a way to write the magic in a way that a normal python interpreter would ignore it (like `#%reset` or something).

Answer (score 2):

i think you can try to add this code 
`import IPython
IPython.start_ipython()`
and see this link--[cant-get-ipython-console-in-spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453400/cant-get-ipython-console-in-spyder)

Comment: ok. I have had a solution of the problem successfully. Firstly, you can open the ipython qtconsloe in the CMD. If you don't open it, the model of ipython is lack in the system. So you should install this modul until the ipython qtconsloe can run. PS:the module lacking is pyzmq and pygments. so you should use the commander line: pip install pyzmq
pip install pygments.